# How to use javascript to make 2 different button show without browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have never been too good with javascript and i cant seem to get any of the tutorials that I've found . I have a button that favorites and un-favorites. I would like it if someone clicks on the favorite button that the un-favorite button shows up without the browser refreshing and so on if they click on the un-favorite button.

Favorite button

```
<button class="follow"><%= link_to "un-Favorite", unfavorite_anime_path(anime), method: :put%></button>
```

Un-favorite button

```
 <button class="follow"><%= link_to "Favorite", favorite_anime_path(anime), method: :put%></button>
```

Controller

```
def favorite
    if @anime = Anime.all
        current_user.mark_as_favorite @anime
        redirect_to @anime = :back
    elsif @amime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:id])
        current_user.mark_as_favorite @anime
    end
end

def unfavorite
    @anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @anime.unmark :favorite, :by => current_user
    redirect_to @anime = :back
end
```

Comment: the easy way will be to have the un-favorite hidden and show it on click of favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add `remote: true` in your `link_to`

2) Give the buttons IDs of `#follow` and `#unfollow`, then use the JS:

```
$('.follow').click(function (event) {
  $('#follow, #unfollow').toggle()
})
```

Provided that one of them is initially set to `display:none`

Comment: It works but when i refresh the browser the button goes back to the favorite button for some reason.

Comment: Ah, that was an oversight. Make a method like `is_favorited` then control the rendering of the button with it in an IF conditional